# Adding a TM superScript to a string

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, symbols, superscript

I need to add the TM(trademark) superscript symbol next to a title in a C# string. is there anyway to possibly do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you on ASP.NET, Web Forms, WPF?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This answer is "\u2122" by Hans Passant™

Use the charmap.exe applet and copy/paste the character in your string literal.

Answer (score 4):

1. Click Start
2. Type **Charmap**
3. Open Charmap
4. Click **Advanced View**
5. Type **mark**
6. Copy desired value
7. Paste to your code