# C# Create a subscript in a string

Tags: c#, string, subscript

Currently I am trying to fix some formatting in my application. I am trying to subscript a `string` and append it to a normal `string`- the same way you can do it in MS word. I already tried this (as supposed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704169/how-to-write-superscript-in-a-string-and-display-using-messagebox-show)):

```
string temp = "NormalText";
foreach( char t in "SubscriptedText".ToCharArray())
    temp += "\x208" + t;

MessageBox.Show(temp);
```

Output:
`NormalTextȈSȈuȈbȈsȈcȈrȈiȈpȈtȈeȈdȈTȈeȈxȈt`

But, as I noted afterwards it is the font who has to support the unicode definitions. And on the internet there doesn't seem to be a font who supports all letters in supscripted format.

So, is there a way to format my text in order to subscript the second half of it? Maybe a simple function I am missing? Or is this just not possible and I have to align my subscripted text on my own?

**EDIT**
Also tried this:

```
string temp = "NormalText";
foreach( char t in "SubscriptedText".ToCharArray())
    temp += "\x208" + (int)t;

MessageBox.Show(temp);
```

But (of course) this didn't work out at all. I've got my output looking like this:

`NormalTextȈ84Ȉ105Ȉ101Ȉ102Ȉ101Ȉ114Ȉ84Ȉ101Ȉ120Ȉ11`

Comment: A string in `C#` doesn't have subscript or superscript. That's an issue for whatever is displaying the string (and a `MessageBox` isn't going to do it). There are a limited subset of superscript and subscript characters in a unicode block but there isn't a general way to make a block of arbitrary characters in a string super or sub script.

Comment: If you want a `MessageBox` that can handle sub and super script, then you will need to create your own that can, for example, display rich text or HTML or some format of your own.

Comment: BTW, what you are doing in your code is adding the Cyrillic capital yi to your string. You are misinterpreting what the Wikipedia page is telling you. For example, `\x2081` would give you a subscript `1`, but it's not telling you that adding `\x208` before a character makes the next character subscript.

Comment: Looks like you have Unicode characters (16 bit wide).  You need to convert to string with encoding.              byte[] input;
            string output = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(input);
You can not fix the issue after the  data was converted to string without using encoding.  Unicode data is a mixture of one and two byte characters.  A string/char is two bytes with a private property indicating if each character is one or two bytes.   Once data is converted to a string improperly it is impossible in string format to fix the alignment of the one and two characters data.

Comment: @MattBurland Okay thank you both.

Could you give me a short inspiration on how I should start displaying richtext format on my own? I think about implementing a class which extends a richtextbox or something?

Comment: Create a form, stick a `RichTextBox` on there and make it read-only.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095583/set-superscript-and-subscript-in-formatted-text-in-wpf) may be helpful if you are using `WPF`

Comment: @HosseinNarimani I am using windows forms. Too bad, because the solution you provided would be perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there are limeted number of symbols which can be used for subscription. There are these symbols:

```
1 - '\u2081'
2-  '\u2082'
3-  '\u2083'
...
9 - '\u2089'
+ - '\u208A'
- - '\u208B'
= - '\u208C'
( - '\u208D'
) - '\u208E'
```

That's all. So you can't subscript the string like "SubscriptedText".

If you want convert to subscription some digit or allowed symbol you can try the following way:

```
void ShowSubText()
    {
        String inputString = "NormalText";
        var nonDigitSymbolsTable = new Dictionary<char, char>();
        nonDigitSymbolsTable.Add('+', 'A');
        nonDigitSymbolsTable.Add('-', 'B');
        nonDigitSymbolsTable.Add('=', 'C');
        nonDigitSymbolsTable.Add('(', 'D');
        nonDigitSymbolsTable.Add(')', 'E');
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        int checkToDigit = 0;
        foreach (char t in "1234567890+-=()".ToCharArray())
        {
            if (int.TryParse(t.ToString(), out checkToDigit))
                temp.Append("\\u208" + t);
            else
                temp.Append("\\u208" + nonDigitSymbolsTable[t]);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(inputString + GetStringFromUnicodeSymbols(temp.ToString()));
    }
    string GetStringFromUnicodeSymbols(string unicodeString)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(unicodeString, @"\\u(?<Value>[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})"))
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat(@"{0}",
                                       (Char)int.Parse(match.Groups["Value"].Value,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Side note: you can use the same code for superscript by using the superscript range instead of subscript one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)